# No such column 'LastPasswordChangeDate' on entity 'User error

Tags: apex, soql, community

I am trying to access LastPasswordChangeDate field on the user object in my apex class. However, when i do so through my community user i am getting no such column of User. If i try through an internal user it works alright. Also, my apex class has been defined as with sharing and if i remove the same the error disappears. Can anyone please let me know the reason and how can i access the field with a with sharing definition of my class?

Comment: Which type of user are you trying to query when running the code as community user,  is it a standard user or the logged-in community user or an external user from another community ?

Comment: It is the logged in community user itself. @Shamina

Comment: How are you trying to access the field? Query? Updating? Looking at the field on [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php) we can see more information about the field. Also if you look at [LastPasswordChangeDate on User Fields reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_fields.htm&type=5), 'This read-only field appears only for users with the Manage Users permission.'. We most likely need more information such as your use case, objective for the code and a snippet too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, you must use `without sharing` in order for a community user to access the User object.  Since you want to use `with sharing` in your class, you must create a separate `without sharing` class and method specifically to retrieve the fields on the User object.

Comment: Thanks. Got it.